# Custom save method with condition in django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to do a django project where a user can describe pictures using one or more taggings, as soon as more than one user has entered the same tagging for the same picture, this word or tagging should be saved to the Tag table.

I thought I can solve this by adding a custom save method to the Tag model. Would this be the right approach or would I write this logic inside a view?

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    LANGUAGES = (('en', 'english'),
                 ('de', 'deutsch'),
                 ('fr', 'francais')
                 )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=LANGUAGES)

class Tagging(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    gameround = models.ForeignKey(Gameround, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, default='')
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Pictures, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taggings', default='')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a new instance of the Tag model whenever a new Tagging object contains a tag that is already in an existing Tagging object (i.e. has been submitted by a different user previously).

I would do that in the view function, when processing the data for a Tagging object. Whenever a user submits new tags (taggings), for each one check if it already [exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#exists) in the database. If yes, create a new instance of the Tag model and populate it with the appropriate data.

```
user_tag = "value of the new tag"

if Tagging.objects.filter(tag=user_tag).exists():
    new_tag = Tag()
    new_tag.name = user_tag
    # set other fields
    new_tag.save()
```

Comment: Thank you! This certainly helps. How would I allow for user input though? Such that I  can pass the user_tag as a parameter to a view method or such?

Comment: Oh, I had assumed that you already have some kind of front-end (the part of your application that lives in the user's browser). The easiest way of doing that would be with a simple HTML page that displays the picture and has a form for user input. You can then retrieve that input with a POST request when the form is submitted.
More sophisticated methods would be using Django templates or a Javascript framework, like React. If these concepts are all completely new to you, you might consider an online course. I can recommend CS50's web programming course (https://cs50.harvard.edu/web/2020/).